# How can I display all the values at the center of the row and the div above row is not taking width same as row below it. how to achieve that?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">

        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <style type="text/css">
         ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
         }
         li{
            height: 64px;
            background-color:pink;
         }
         .a{
            height: 64px;   
         }
         .ab{
                display: flex;
                direction: row;
            align-items: center;
         }
         }
         .b{
            display: flex;
            direction: row-reverse;
            align-items: center;
         }
         .secondli{
            margin-top: 20px;
         }
        </style>
          <title>Document</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div class="container" >
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-6" >
               <p>mwiiwiw</p>

              <ul>
                <li>
                    <div style="width: 100%">
                        <span>Xyz</span>
                        <span>sjfoeij</span>
                    </div>
                <div class="row a">

               <div class="col-12 col-md-8  ab" style="background-color: aqua;">
                <span class="b">ABC</span>
            </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 b"style="background-color: yellow;" >
                <span>11</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
         <li class="secondli">
                <div class="row a">
               <div class="col-12 col-md-8  ab" >
                <span class="b">ABC</span>
            </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 b" >
                <span>11</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </body>

        </html>
```

How can I display all the values at the center of the row?And the div with spans value Xyz  is not taking width same as row below it.And also the second row is not taking width same as row above?
How can I achieve that using bootstrap and Css. Can we add two li and a row inside li or we will have to add container as well inside

Comment: Please provide the expected result in drawing. Question is not clear enough

Comment: Question is not clear, Please provide the your expected answer So will work accordingly @irkhaladkar

Comment: @Ajay Malhotra Expected output should be as follow:-                                                                1) Xyz sjfoe should take same width as ABC and 11 row                                                           2) ABC and 11 should be displayed at center of the li                                                              3) And the second li which is added should also span same width as of ABC and 11 row

Comment: @Mulli Expected output should be as follow:- 1) Xyz sjfoe should take same width as ABC and 11 row 2) ABC and 11 should be displayed at center of the li 3) And the second li which is added should also span same width as of ABC and 11 row

Comment: Hi, Thank for you the comment @irkhaladkar. Still the information provided by you is limited. It would be good if you provide expected design or image. Anyways, As per my understanding about your Question I have added the Answer with code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
 div{
   height: 80px;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 30px;
 }
</style>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" >
       <p>mwiiwiw</p>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: aqua;">
          <span class="b">XYZ</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 b"style="background-color: yellow;" >
          <span>Sjfoeij</span>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: blue;">
        <span class="b">ABC</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 b"style="background-color: red;" >
        <span>11</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: aqua;" >
        <span class="b">ABC</span>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow;" >
        <span>11</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Though answer looks good, please explain the answer a little bit in words or through comments.

Comment: Sure, next time I'll keep your suggestions in my mind.   Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment @irkhaladkar below is the code snippet:

```css
ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
     }
     li{
        /*height: 64px;
        background-color:pink;*/
     }
     .pink{background:pink;}
        .h-64{height:64px}
        .a{
        height: 64px;   
     }
     .ab{
            display: flex;
            direction: row;
        align-items: center;
     }
     }
     .b{
        display: flex;
        direction: row-reverse;
        align-items: center;
     }
     .secondli{
        margin-top: 20px;
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    

      <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-6" >
           <p>mwiiwiw</p>

          <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="row pink">
                    <span class="col-12 col-md-6">Xyz</span>
                    <span class="col-12 col-md-6">sjfoeij</span>
                </div>
            <div class="row h-64">

           <div class="col-12 col-md-6  ab" style="background-color: aqua;">
            <span class="b">ABC</span>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ab"style="background-color: yellow;" >
            <span>11</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
     <li class="secondli">
            <div class="row h-64 pink">
           <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ab" >
            <span class="">ABC</span>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ab" >
            <span>11</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```